# Using user-space functions like sprintf in the kernel, or not?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am making a /proc entry for my driver. So, in the read callback function the first argument is the location into which we write the data intended for the user. I searched on how to write   the data in it and i could see that everybody is using **sprintf** for this purpose. I am surprised to see that it works in kernel space. However this should be wrong to use a user space function in kernel space. Also i cant figure out how to write in that location without using any user space function like strcpy, sprintf, etc. I am using kernel version 3.9.10. Please suggest me how i should do this without using sprintf or any other user space function.

Comment: Its best to add some sample code of what you are trying to achieve, if you want quicker responses.

Comment: What you are looking for is proc_create(). Please read relevant sections, for example [seq_file](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/seq_file.txt), from kernel documentation tree and try to come up with some code. Stack Overflow is not a free programming service, so it is considered to be good behaviour to produce some code and then asking specific questions about the code you already have produced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the 'normal' user-space functions would make no sense in kernel code, so they are not available in the kernel.

However, some functions like `sprintf`, `strcpy`, or `memcpy` *are* useful in kernel code, so the kernel implements them (more or less completely) and makes them available for drivers.
See [include/linux/kernel.h](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/kernel.h) and [string.h](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/string.h).

Answer (score 1):

`sprintf` is a kernel-space function in Linux. It is totally separate from its user-space namesake and may or may not work identically to it.

Just because a function in user-space exist, it does not mean an identically named function in kernel-space cannot.